# Gradle - Understanding how to deploy a transitive depedancy with my library

Tags: gradle

So I have MyApp and a Libary MyLibary1. I would like to use MyLibary1 in MyApp. However at runtime in MyApp I get errors because MyLibary1 depends on a class from MyLibary2. How can I setup my Libary1 to have MyLibary2 with it and how can MyApp uptake it? I have a RootProject that both MyLibrary1 and MyLibrary2 belong to

Answer (score 0):

The `MyLibrary2` project is not correctly 'exporting' its dependencies for them to be available to `MyLibary1` and `MyApp`.

`MyLibrary2` needs to make use of the [Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) which as the name implies, to make Java libraries. It will then need to be published to some repository using the [Maven Publishing Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)